# Expressões regulares

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho um pouco de dificuldade para montar as expressões regulares, estou tentando trabalhar com este código:

```
<?php 
$url = file_get_contents('http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/precosdiarios/');
preg_match_all($expressao, $url, $conteudo);
echo $conteudo; 
?>
```

Eu preciso pegar os preços entre esses códigos:

```
<tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td style="width:170px;">
        Mandioca para mesa
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;">
        Mogi Mirim
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="width:70px;">
        11,50
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width:70px;">
        cx.23 kg
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px;">
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridRecebidos_ctl95_PanelGridObs">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:170px;">
        Mandioca para mesa
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;">
        Pindamonhangaba
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="width:70px;">
        28,00
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width:70px;">
        cx.23 kg
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px;">
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridRecebidos_ctl96_PanelGridObs">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td style="width:170px;">
        Mandioca para mesa
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;">
        Sorocaba
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="width:70px;">
        8,79
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="width:70px;">
        cx.23 kg
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px;">
        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridRecebidos_ctl97_PanelGridObs">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Para pega o preço de cada cidade:

-Qual seria o melhor padrão para utilizar?

Comment: Você está querendo pegar o conteúdo de outra página da internet?

Comment: Dica: não use regex para parsear HTML, de uma olhada em XPath, YQL e htmlSQL

Comment: Sim,estou querendo pegar a cotação de um produto que é atualizado diariamente.
Vou dar uma olhada em XPath e YQL.

Comment: Para PHP há o htmlSQL (https://github.com/hxseven/htmlSQL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ideal mesmo é usar XPATH para pegar esses preços.
Olhando essa página que você informou ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/precosdiarios/");

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
// essa query pega o todos os TDs na posicao 3 da primeira tabela com a classe "tabela_dados"
$nodes = $xpath->query("(//table[@class='tabela_dados'])[1]/tr/td[position()=3]");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . "\n"; // vai imprimir todos os preços
}
```

Comment: Obrigado,chegando em casa testarei

Comment: Tem o DOM também (que acho mais simples)

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/precosdiarios/, line: 3654 in 
Esse erro você sabe o motivo?

Comment: Adicione _libxml_use_internal_errors(true);_ no início do código. Apesar do aviso deve funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de eu acessar uma determinada posição da variável $nodes,como se fosse um vetor?

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira se essa resposta resolve sua dúvida original, você pode marcá-la como aceita. Veja mais em [tour].

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Você pode acessar assim: `$node->item(3); // retorna item na posição 3`. Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta que resolveu seu problema como aceita :)

Comment: @AndréRibeiro ja marquei a resposta como aceita.Sobre o que eu perguntei ali em cima eu ainda não consegui entender,ficaria $nodes->nodeValue(3); ou esse item é para ser item mesmo?,pois como eu sei qual posição que está a palavra que eu quero eu não precisaria do foreach,Obg mesmo assim

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Seria `$node->item(3)` pra pegar o item na posição 3. `item` é um método.

Answer (score 4):

Consegui fazer com esta regex:

```
<tr[^>]*>\s*<td[^>]*>[^<]*<\/td>\s*<td[^>]*>[^<]*<\/td>\s*<td[^>]*>\s*(\S*)
```

É importante você capturar todos os matches que resultarem.

Como esta expressão funciona?

Vamos quebrá-las em partes:

1. `<tr[^>]*>` - Comece com `<tr`, em seguida use o `[^>]>` para pular tudo até encontrar um `>` e consome o `>`. Ou seja, isso consome o `<tr blablabla>`. Também funciona se houver apenas `<tr>`.
2. `\s*` - Consume um monte de espaços em branco e quebras de linhas.
3. `<td[^>]*>[^<]*<\/td>\s*` - Comece com `<td`, em seguida use o `[^>]>` para pular tudo até encontrar o `>` e consome o `>`. Continua consumindo até encontrar mais um `<` e em seguida consome o `</td>` e os espaços em branco e quebras de linha que se seguem. Ou seja, consome o primeiro `<td blabla>blablabla</td>`.
4. A mesma coisa do item 3, vai consumir o segundo `<td blabla>blablabla</td>`.
5. `<td[^>]*>\s*` - Consome o `<td blabla>` que se segue e os espaços em branco e quebras de linha. Logo após isso, temos o preço.
6. `(\S*)` - Captura todos os caracteres que se seguem até encontrar um espaço em branco (e não consome o espaço em branco). Ou seja, isso capturará o preço.

Testado [aqui](https://www.regex101.com/). Para verificar, coloque a regex no primeiro campo e `g` no segundo. Na área abaixo coloque o texto aonde você quer fazer a busca (no caso o HTML).

Comment: Não testei pois não estou em casa,tem como você me explicar mais ou menos como criou está expressão,para ver se consigo entender rs

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira Resposta editada. :)