# Acessar determinada linha da variavel

Tags: php, xpath

Há um tempo atrás fiz uma pergunta sobre expressões regulares e um usuário [me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46752/4751) utilizando este código, usando `xpath`:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/precosdiarios/");

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
// essa query pega o todos os TDs na posicao 3 da primeira tabela com a classe  
$nodes = $xpath->query("(//table[@class='tabela_dados'])[1]/tr/td[position()=3]");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . "\n"; // vai imprimir todos os preços
}
```

Na documentação do `xpath` a descrição da forma como os dados dos "nodes" são armazenados não ficou clara para o meu entendimento.

Existe uma maneira de acessar um determinado espaço do "nodes" sem o uso do `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O retorno do método `query()` do objeto `DomXPath` é um objeto do tipo [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php).

É possível acessar os itens dessa lista através do método `item()`:

```
<?php

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/precosdiarios/");

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// Estava faltando um "tbody" antes do "tr"
$nodes = $xpath->query("(//table[@class='tabela_dados'])[1]/tbody/tr/td[position()=3]");

// Na pagina que você está carregando existem espaços em branco
// dentro das células pesquisadas. Nesse caso usei o trim pra limpá-los
echo trim($nodes->item(8)->nodeValue);
```

Note que a lista de `DOMNodeList` se inicia com a posição `0`